# How to connect oracle to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

I did everything according to the instructions. Downloaded instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0. Unpacked, added to the "Path" system variable. I downloaded php-8.0.6-Win32-vs16-x64, unpacked it, added it to the "Path" system variable. Specified extension_dir, uncommented extension = oci8_12c, rebooted. I run Composer-Setup.exe, the error "Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (% 1 is not a Win32 application)" appears. Everything was downloaded 64, tried all the recommendations of the Internet, was not crowned with success, tell me, how to be.

Comment: a quick internet search shows many solutions to try.  Did you look at any of those?

Comment: considered the proposed solutions all day

Comment: do you connect the latest versions correctly? A year ago, the same procedure led to a positive result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.3.0.0 (downloaded a year ago), changed php version from 8 to 7.4, and it worked. It took several days of a dull bulkhead of all the available options, until I found a surviving old client of Orakl. Nobody advised anything sensible on the Internet. I have been doing web development quite recently, can someone tell me how this problem should have been solved correctly? (and not fully resolved, it still does not work with the eight)